# Looking for techniques to add suffix to resources to make their name unique

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am creatig a few azure resources (Such as storage accounts) that their name must be unique accross Azure.

Is there any technique in Terraform scripting that allows adding a random string to the end of resources so their name become uniqu accorss Azure?

What is the common pattern to deal with this requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure yes, you can create resource random_string and use in in names:

```
resource "random_string" "random" {
  length = 16
  special = true
  override_special = "/@£$"
}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "foo" {
  name                 = "bar-${random_string.random.result}"
  ...
}
```

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/string

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Azure there is a really descent Naming module.  It helps with consistent and randomized naming.  You can reference it [here](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Azure/naming/azurerm/latest).